# Retrieving one row of record from a has many association query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Restaurant Load (1.5ms)  SELECT * FROM "restaurants" INNER JOIN "restaurant_branches" ON "restaurant_branches"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."restaurant_id"
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| resta... | res_... | res_... | crea... | updat... | user_id | resta... | addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | numb... | numb... | email |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 27       | DOGG... | WE S... | 2014... | 2014-... | 4       | 28       | 405 ... |         | CHICAGO | IL      | 60666   | USA     |         |         |       |
| 27       | DOGG... | WE S... | 2014... | 2014-... | 4       | 29       | 111 ... |         | CHICAGO | IL      | 60661   | USA     |         |         |       |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

As you can see from my rails console output there are two lines of record for the restaurant. However, there are two different addresses. How would I do this in my controller's `show` section so that only that particular row gets passed unto my `show.html.erb` form?

Currently, this is what my show has:

```
    class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @restaurant = Restaurant.select('*').joins(:restaurant_branches)
  end

  def show
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    #@restaurant = Restaurant.select('*').joins(:restaurant_branches).find_by.restaurant_branch(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  def create
    if user_signed_in?
      @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
      if @restaurant.save
        redirect_to @restaurant
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_owner_session_path
    end
  end

  def edit
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    if @restaurant.update_attributes(restaurant_params)
      flash.now[:notice] = "You have successfully updated #{@restaurant.res_name.titleize}."
      redirect_to @restaurant
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    @restaurant.destroy
    flash.now[:notice] = "#{@restaurant.res_name.titleize} has been deleted!"
    redirect_to restaurants_url
  end

  private

  def restaurant_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(:res_name, :res_description, restaurant_branches_attributes: [ :id, :address_line1, :address_line2, :address_line3, :address_line4, :address_line5, :address_line6, :number_phone, :number_fax, :email, :_destroy, pictures_attributes: [ :id, :name, :image, :_destroy] ] ).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

I tried doing something like `@restaurant = Restaurant.joins(:restaurant_branches).find(params[:id])` but am not finding any luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your models and your routes?

Comment: Which of restaurants(branches) do you want to display??, if it's just the restaurant then you don't need the `joins` if it is one if the branches then you need a `where`

Comment: Can you explain more bjhaid? Perhaps a sample? I am new to RoR and I just come from a SQL backend so ActiveRecord is a bit tricky for me as of yet.

Comment: Which restaurant branch do you intend to display

Comment: Either one, depends on which "show" link they click. I tried find_by and even where but I am not sure I am getting it right.

Comment: `RestaurantBranch.find(params[:id])` is more like what you want

Comment: It would work, but the parent Model is Restaurant and that's what the controller is calling from.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try finding the record by restaurant_branch instead of the id?

```
    def show
      @restaurant = Restaurant.find_by_restaurant_branch(params[:id])
    end
```

Comment: I am getting a NoMethodError at find_by_restaurant_branch.

Comment: @svajone This should be written as `@restaurant = Restaurant.find_by(restaurant_branch_id: params[:id])` . params[:id] should include the restaurant_branch_id. This will return the first record that the query finds.